# Asymptotic behavior of a series involving binomial coefficients.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it correct that the series ($n,m>0$)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{2k+n}{k}\frac{1}{4^k\sqrt{k+m}}
$$
diverges as $\sim\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{k(k+m)}}$?

If so what is the value of
$$
\lim_{K\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\log K}\sum_{k=0}^K\binom{2k+n}{k}\frac{1}{2^{2k+n}\sqrt{k}}?
$$

Comment: Does Mathematica do anything for the case $n=m=0$ ?

Answer (score 2):

By [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),
$$
\binom{2\,k}{k}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\,k}}\,4^k.
$$
Since
$$
\binom{2\,k+n}{k}\ge\binom{2\,k}{k},
$$
the series diverges for all $n,m$.